# A Gerrit patchset depends on a outdated patchset

Tags: git, gerrit

[image]

What i have done:

1. push a patch to gerrit
2. make a tag
3. push tags
4. admin user merge this patch to master

i cannot find any answer for this problem. And the most important thing is this patch depends on itself.

Comment: you see this patch depends on the patch which it Needed by

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem:

Your change (CHANGE-2) depends on another (CHANGE-1) but the patchset (commit) of the CHANGE-2 used as the base for CHANGE-1 is outdated. In other words: somebody (or the Gerrit itself) created a second patchset for the CHANGE-1 and now CHANGE-2 is depending on a patchset that will never be integrated (merged) to the branch.

You have something like this:

```
BASE --- CHANGE-1_PATCHSET-1 --- CHANGE-2_PATCHSET-1
  \
   \--- CHANGE-1_PATCHSET-2
```

You need to rebase CHANGE-2 to have something like this:

```
BASE --- CHANGE-1_PATCHSET-1 --- CHANGE-2_PATCHSET-1
  \
   \--- CHANGE-1_PATCHSET-2 --- CHANGE-2_PATCHSET-2
```

Depending on your Gerrit version and the changes (if you will have conflicts or not) you can do this easily using the Rebase button on Gerrit UI. If you have an old Gerrit version or you find conflicts you'll need to execute the "git rebase" manually (something like: git rebase CHANGE-1_PATCHSET-2_commit.

Comment: thanks for your answer！But i cannot rebase this patch，it's already merge to the master branch,it meaning it's do anything fun before this patch been merged. My point is this patch depends on the patch which it also Needed by . BTW：how to do a painting like you

Comment: The patch is not merged... this is not possible. Look at the message: Change depends on 1 outdated change(s) and should be rebased on the latest patch sets. Go to the change page (https://GERRIT-SERVER/#/c/CHANGE-NUMBER/) and search for then change status. Let me know the result. What did you mean by "how to do a painting like you"?

Comment: I will show this page about 10 hours later.  How did you do this :

BASE --- CHANGE-1_PATCHSET-1 --- CHANGE-2_PATCHSET-1
                \
                 \--- CHANGE-1_PATCHSET-2 --- CHANGE-2_PATCHSET-2

Comment: I used a text editor first, then I copied/pasted in the answer window and finally I formated like "code sample".

Comment: Yes, this status is `Review in Progress` ,but i clone the project, this commit already exist, the change-id is the same.

Comment: First check if it was really integrated in master (you can have the same Change-Id in different branches). If it is integrated in master, maybe Admin (you wrote that it was the Admin who integrated it) submitted the commit straight to the branch (push to refs/heads/master instead of refs/for/master) bypassing Gerrit. If he/she did this than you can just "Abandon" the change.

Comment: thanks again，I abandon this change，but nothing happen

Comment: What did you expect to happen?

Comment: I want abandon this patch, but it's already merged. i think the only thing i can do is delete this project and recreate it.

Comment: Don't do that... you don't need to delete the project only because some commit was sent straight to the branch without code review. Forget about this commit and just move on.

Comment: I hope so, but this unwanted commit has already been merged to master branch.Because i see this commit when i clone this repo.

Comment: Just use "git revert" to do a new commit which reverts the unwanted one, push to Gerrit, approve and submit it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Finally i fix this issus by push a new commit like you say.